# jqGrid error on sorting datetime column

Tags: jquery, datetime, sorting, jqgrid

When I set `[ sorttype: "datetime", datefmt: "d/m/Y H:i:s" ]` to a jQuery grid, I get a message error when sorting a datetime column.

The message is: `undefined`. But, this only happens in IE 8/9, on Firefox it works fine.

I have some tables created dynamically. One table created is like this:

```
<table id="files_1">
  <thead> 
    <tr>
      <th>Sequencial</th>
      <th>File</th> 
      <th>Datetime</th>
      <th>Size</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>File 1</td>
    <td>07/04/2011 09:28:00</td>
    <td>100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>File 2</td>
    <td>07/03/2011 09:28:00</td>
    <td>101</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

After this comes a javascript function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    tableToGrid("#files_1", {
        height: 'auto',
        width: '100%',  
        rowNum: '2',
        rowTotal: '2', 
        hoverrows: true,
        colNames: ['', 'File', 'Datetime', 'Size (bytes)'],
        colModel: [
            {name:'Sequencial', index:'Sequencial', width: '30', stype:'text',  align: 'center', sorttype:'number'},
            {name:'File', index:'File', width: '370', stype:'text',  align: 'left'}, 
            {name:'Datetime', index:'Datetime', width: '', stype:'text',  align: 'center', datefmt: "d/m/Y H:i:s", sorttype: 'date'},
            {name:'Size', index:'Size', width: '', stype:'text', align: 'center', sorttype:'number'},
        ]
    });
});
```

The grid is created and works fine.

It sorts all the columns, except the datetime column.

When I try to sort this column (in IE 8 or IE 9) it returns a beautiful short message (undefined), from the grid, not a javascript error. It is as if the grid could not get some element/attribute while sorting.

Comment: which data you use for the grid? How you fill the grid? Do you use `formatter:'date'`? The full code example which can be used to reproduce the problem is the best.

Comment: you should **modify** your original question and append any information which are needed instead of writing answers on his own question. It make the reading of your question much easier. Moreover you should write comment starting with @Oleg if you want that somebody read it (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) for details)

Answer (score 2):

Try use a complete date format information:

```
 {
  name:'Datetime', 
  index:'Datetime', 
  width: '', 
  formatter:'date', 
  formatoptions: {newformat:'m/d/Y'}, 
  datefmt: 'd-M-Y', 
  sorttype: 'date'
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are one more simple error: comma before ] at the end of `colModel` definition. The combination `},]` is the syntax error.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Fernando.htm) include the code which you posted and I see no errors at least in IE9.

You can additionally verify that in your version of jquery.jqGrid.min.js which you downloaded the following modules are included: grid.base.js, grid.common.js, grid.tbltogrid.js. To do this you can just open jquery.jqGrid.min.js in the text editor and search in the comment at the beginning of the file after the words "Modules:" for grid.base.js, grid.common.js, grid.tbltogrid.js.

Comment: Another detail is that I was calling this by ajax. On success was addind the response to a div by $("#divId").html(response). I discovered that IE doesn't works very well with this way to add content. Then I changed the command to $("#divId").append(response) and it passed works fine in Firefox thus such as in IE. Important: the included files (js and css of the jqgrid) was in the file called by ajax. I changed it to the header of the file that calls the ajax. Now, everything is working...